# Ckeditor buttons id are changing through browsers

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, ckeditor, mozilla

Currently using CKEditor, I need to get the buttons id in my toolbar to apply some specific CSS and to get positions of certains button for exemple.

But with Google chrome, the ids of the buttons aren't the same than with mozilla or IE.

An exemple would be more clear:

If i have the samme toolbar, the same code, mozilla will show me this:

```
<span id="cke_1_top>
    <span id="cke_7">Toolbar</span>

     // My first group of buttons, which contains 2 buttons
    <span id="cke_9" class="cke_toolbar" role = "toolbar">
         // Code for buttons
    </span>

    // My second group of buttons
    <span id="cke_12" class="cke_toolbar" role = "toolbar">
         // Code for buttons
    </span>
</span>
```

While chrome will display this:

```
<span id="cke_1_top>
    <span id="cke_8">Toolbar</span>
     // My first group of buttons, which contains 2 buttons
    <span id="cke_10" class="cke_toolbar" role = "toolbar">
         // Code for buttons
    </span>

    // My second group of buttons
    <span id="cke_13" class="cke_toolbar" role = "toolbar">
         // Code for buttons
    </span>

</span>
```

So my css, for exemple:

```
#cke_13{
    color: red
}
```

Will work only with Chrome, because this id do not exist if the code is displayed by mozilla.

For the moment the problem appears only with chrome, all the ids are increased by one.

Does anyone know where the problem could be? Or at least is there a way to choose the id of a button at the creation of it?

I really don't know why this is happening, any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: That ID might not be the best way to style your elements.

Answer (score 0):

The general way of changing CKEditor skin should be performed by obtaining the [source version](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_source.html), making changes in `ckeditor/skins` and [building the editor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_build.html).

If however you need to change only specific buttons then please note that each button has a unique class assigned which you can change with the same styles or same JavaScript code across different browsers. Please see: [image].

If you need to change toolbar groups (element holding a group of buttons) then unfortunately there are no unique id's or classes and the only way I can recommend is getting a specific button by its unique class and then getting its closest parent (with JavaScript) which has the class `cke_toolbar` or `cke_toolgroup` and is a `span`.